# Are zombie processes something I should be concerned about?

Tags: process, zombie-process

I run a server. Should I be concerned about zombie processes? Do they consume any system resources (RAM, process table entry, etc.) that I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zombies do not consume any system resources.  They have already deallocated memory.  So, you do not need to be concerned.